# Universally Accepted Beer Education

Tags: recommendations, cicerone

I have been searching for Beer education with universally accepted certificate like WSET for a while but I couldn't find one. I've found some courses Prud'homme ,Cicerone, and The Beer Judge Certification Program (BJCP) but I don't think they are like WSET. 
Are there any training program like WSET for beer?

Comment: What do you mean by education?  Taste/judge or brew?

Comment: More like combination of theoretical training and tasting. For example, Pilsner lecture should generally include brewing techniques, ingredients like types of hops and grains are used (maybe their special characters and their impact on a beer), and of course at the end tasting.

Answer (score 3):

Just like there is no standards for understanding Computer Science education there is no standardized wine or beer education. You get the education where you can. I have pretty extensive experience in both wine and beer education. At one time, long ago, I was a BJCP certified judge. I have a winemaking certificate from UC Davis (short course) Both were a rigorous education. Then I went on to start a winery and eventually taught at a local community college that has a 2 year wine program. I think only the lead instructor had anything like a masters in wine (MW) the rest of us just university classes and self taught.

Getting a degree in brewing from an accredited college like UC Davis would have the most clout. I wouldn't say the WSET is universally accepted as the "gold standard" in wine education. If all you want to do is get some type of certificate for being a server then the Cicerone or BJCP will probably serve the purpose. Getting a [Master Cicerone](https://www.cicerone.org/us-en/certifications/master-cicerone) would probably be the highest for beer. Beer education has always been less formal than winemaking. I'm not sure why since brewing beer is way more complicated than making wine. I'm sure it has to do with the snobbery associated with wine vs. the everyman appeal associated with beer.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the BJCP certifications, as well as the Certified Cicerone(r) are the most universally recognized across the craft beer industry.

There are many brewing degrees available as well, ranging from certificates to advanced vocational trades and brewmaster educations more common in countries that treat brewing as a tradeskill.

It depends on your industry focus, BJCP is most focused on homebrewing, judging homebrewing, and the historical preservation and relevence of beer styles.

The Cicerone program is concerned with a well rounded understanding of beer, draft line systems and maintenance, and service. It's suited for primarily industry professionals in a front-of-house role, sales representatives, or Brewers honing their sensory evaluation. The Cicerone program uses the BJCP guidelines for style recognition.

Degrees are usually for production Brewers, lab technicians wishing to specialize in beer quality assurance, or sales personnel looking to further their depth of knowledge in regard to the brewing process. Every school will be slightly different, and may be taught according to a general regional style of brewing, (German, English, Belgian), and will differ in style of brewing as well as elective material, but will usually cover the science in regard to wort production and fermentation.

And finally, brewing itself can often be a heavy amount of on the job training, with some of the most knowledgeable brewers never having a formal certification, but just a wealth of work experience.

There is nothing entirely universal or recognized as a complete education at this time.